# Comparing i in loop with the next value and also accessing the last value

Tags: c#, for-loop, indexing

In my string I'm looking to compare one value with the next. So given IVI, I want to check if V is followed by I, then add 4. If not, just add 1.

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++){
            if(s[i] == 'I'){
                if(s[i+1] == 'V'){
                    Console.WriteLine("1");
                    sum += 4;
                }
                else if(s[i] == 'X'){
                  Console.WriteLine("2");
                    sum += 9;
                }
                else{
                    Console.WriteLine("3");
                    sum += roman[s[i]];
                }
    }
```

But it goes out of bounds with s[i+1], but how do I stop it from checking that far? If I use s.Length-1, then I won't be able to get the last value.

Comment: Surely you can compare `i` to `s.Length` before accessing `s[i+1]`? If statements aren't limited to one condition, you can use `&&` (and) and `||` (or) to combine multiple conditions.

Comment: If you would be converting Roman numerals to integers you'd use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711746/i-am-trying-to-figure-out-how-to-convert-roman-numerals-into-integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add one more condition:

```
            if(i <= s.length - 1 && s[i+1] == 'V'){
```